# How to get all Errors from ASP.Net webAPI modelState at once?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

I am trying to validate my model using data annotations but unfortunately, I couldn't able get all validation errors at once for example

below are my model and API

```
public class Data 

     {
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "TransactionId value must be greater than zero")]
        public int TransactionId { get; set; }
        [Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/1900", "1/1/2099", ErrorMessage = AppConstants.InvalidDate)]
        public DateTime TransactionCreationDate { get; set; }
        [Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/1900", "1/1/2099", ErrorMessage = AppConstants.InvalidDate)]
        public DateTime educationYearStart { get; set; }
        [Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/1900", "1/1/2099", ErrorMessage = AppConstants.InvalidDate)]
        public DateTime educationYearDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Marks> marks { get; set; }
 }
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("create/marks")]
        public IActionResult Add([FromBody]Data model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            return Ok("Created Successfully");
        }
    }
```

my input

```
{
    "transactionId": 0,
    "transactionCreationDate": "2021-08-31T22:37:57.5311707+05:30",
    "educationYearStart": "",
    "educationYearYearEnd": "2021-08-31T22:37:57.5311707+05:30",
    "name":"sss"
    "stuDetails": [
        {
            "subjectCode": "Engilsh",         
            "totalMarks": 100,
            "Marks": 80
        },
         {
            "subjectCode": "Maths",         
            "totalMarks": 100,
            "Marks": 70
        },
    ]
}
```

I get the following output:

> "transactionCreationDate": [
> "The input was not valid."
> ]

But I was expecting something similar to:

> "transactionCreationDate": [
> "The input was not valid."
> ] , "TransactionId":["TransactionId value must be greater than zero"]

How to get all validations errors at once in c# webAPI?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values) {
foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors) {
    .....
}
```

}

Now you can concatenate errors or do whatever you like with them and return them in `return BadRequest`.